# How to determine the drawing state of a JFrame?

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, screenshot

I want to take a screenshot of Java `JFrame`.

Sometimes the frame rendering is not finished, but the screenshot operation is complete.**But sometimes he does not appear this situation, as if the root computer performance has a certain relationship!**

[Situation screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ug8Ky.jpg) <--- Situation screenshots

I think I can delay the screenshot with `Thread.sleep()`，but can't determine `sleep()` length of time.

#### Java code:

```java
package com.richardtang.apktesttool;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test2 {

    public static Robot robot;

    static {
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
            jPanel.add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(i)));
        }

        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setSize(500, 500);
        jFrame.setContentPane(jPanel);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);

        BufferedImage img = captureFrame(jFrame);
        try {
            ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("/tmp/1.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static BufferedImage captureFrame(JFrame window) {
        window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        Point windowPoint = window.getLocation();
        Dimension windowSize = window.getSize();
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(
                (int) windowPoint.getX(),
                (int) windowPoint.getY(),
                windowSize.width,
                windowSize.height
        );
        return robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
    }
}
```

Comment: `import cn.hutool.core.swing.RobotUtil;` For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [SwingUtilities invokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)). As per the documentation, `invokeLater` *causes doRun.run() to be executed asynchronously on the AWT event dispatching thread. This will happen **after all pending AWT events have been processed***. Thus, the screenshot will be captured after the frame/panel drawing is completed.

### Update

As @camickr correctly pointed out, ensure that your GUI is also created in a similar way i.e., on the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Example below.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ScreenCapture {
    JFrame jFrame = null;

    public void createGUI() {
        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
            jPanel.add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(i)));
        }

        jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setSize(500, 500);
        jFrame.setContentPane(jPanel);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void capture() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    BufferedImage img = captureFrame(jFrame);
                    ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("tmp/1.png"));
                } catch (AWTException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScreenCapture sc = new ScreenCapture();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                sc.createGUI();
                sc.capture();
            }
        });
    }

    public static BufferedImage captureFrame(JFrame window) throws AWTException {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        Point windowPoint = window.getLocation();
        Dimension windowSize = window.getSize();
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle((int) windowPoint.getX(), (int) windowPoint.getY(), windowSize.width,
                windowSize.height);
        return robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but you also need to make sure that the GUI is created on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. Read the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.